# Deleting a Leaf node BST

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement an AVL tree just for the sake of learning. I managed to make the insertion, but I'm stuck at the deletion. I have a problem deleting a leaf node (the one-child case works just fine). The problem is that when I delete the node it doesn't get erased form the BST, instead, its value just turns 0, so the tree never goes unbalanced when a node is deleted. What I'm basically doing is, if I encounter with a node with no childs, I just free it. Here is the code of the function (without the re balancing part):

```
node_t *Delete ( node_t *root, int num ){

   if ( !root ){
     printf ("Not Found\n");
     return root;
   }

//=======Search for the Element=============

   if ( num > root->data )
       Delete ( root->right , num );

   else if ( num < root->data )
       Delete ( root->left , num );

//======Delete element==============

   else if ( num == root->data ){

     if ( root->right && root->left ){ //two child case

         node_t *auxP = root->right;

         while ( auxP->left ) //finding the successor 
            auxP=auxP->left; 

         root->data = auxP->data; 

         root->right = Delete ( root->right, auxP->data );     
     }

     else{ //one or no child

         if ( !root->right && !root->left ){ // no childs
           free(root);       
         }
         else{ //one child
             node_t *auxP = ( root->right ?  root->right : root->left );
             *root=*auxP;
             free(auxP);
         }                
     }  

   }
  return root;
}
```

If i have a tree like this:

```
        10
       /  \
      5    15 
     / \    \
    2   6    17
```

and i try to delete 6, it ends like this

```
        10
       /  \
      5   15 
     / \    \
    2   0    17
```

It may be an obvious error, but I cant find it. Any explanation of why it isn't working will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please go through this an understand how delete works : http://geeksquiz.com/binary-search-tree-set-2-delete/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete a node, you need change the according child field of its parent. But in your code, you only pass in the node-to-delete itself (`node_t *root`) so the parent node is left unchanged. In the single child case, you work around it by copying the single child to the node-to-delete, and remove the single child instead. But in the leaf case, you do nothing to fix the link in parent.

One way is to somehow pass the parent node in so that when the node-to-delete is a leaf, break the link from the parent and set the according child of parent to `NULL`.

Alternatively, you can add a parent link to the node definition so that when you delete a node, you can derive the parent link from it.

Comment: thank you for the response, indeed, that was the problem. I corrected it assigning the recursive call (in the search part) to the left/right child of the actual node and returning NULL at the moment of the deletion, So the parent's right/left child will be now NULL.